# Using probability density functions to calculate unconventional probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm given a pdf $p(x)=e^{-x}$ and am supposed to calculate two probabilities that seem unconventional to determine from a pdf. Specifically, I need to calculate $P(x=2)$ and $P(1<x<2)$.

For $P(x=2$), my intuition tells me that since there are an infinite number of possibilities for $x$, $P(x=2)$ must be effectively $0$. However, since I know $x=2$ is a valid value, this seems to contradict my intuition.

As for $P(1<x<2)$, this seems unconventional because the standard usage of a pdf tells you how to calculate $P(a\leq x \leq b)$. Since the end points are not included in my problem, I am not sure wha to change (though a part of me seems to recall that the answer is the same in both cases).

I know how to calculate the probability that a random variable $X$ will lie in some inclusive range (via the integral equation), but not for a discrete value of $X$ or an exclusive range. How would I go about calculating these results?

Comment: You're right that $\mathbb{P}(X=2)=0$, since the PDF you gave is for a continuous random variable. This is the same reason why the end points you mentioned in the second bit don't matter. You can have either hard or soft inequalities and you'll come to the same conclusion.

Comment: Following that line of reasoning, would it then stand that $P(X=1 || X=2)=0$ as well?

Comment: Why do you accept an answer 5 minutes after it is posted if you are still asking questions?

Comment: Because my original questions were answered sufficiently.

Comment: Yes @flubsy, since again you need to evaluate the pdf at the given points where there is no $\delta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as there is no $\delta$ at the integral boundaries (like in the given pdf) you can write:

$$\Pr(a<X<b)=\Pr(a\le X<b)=\Pr(a<X\le b)=\Pr(a \le X\le b)=\int_a^bf_X(x)dx$$

In such case $\Pr(X=a)=\Pr(X=b)=0$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

As measure_theory mentioned in his comment, the probability of a continuous random variable taking a single discrete value is indeed zero, so your intuition is correct.

The second part of your question can be answered by using the same idea as the first. As we have $ P(X=a) = 0 $ , it follows that $ P(X < a) = P(X <= a) $ ,and, $ P(X>a) = P(X>=a) $.

This means that the inequality sign in your question makes no difference if it is an "smaller than" or "smaller than or equal to". You can simply evaluate it in the normal way by integrating $ p(x) $ between the interval in the usual way. I do agree with you however that it is non-standard notation, but it is not rare to see.